# How to convert CMYK eps to CMYK jpeg with ghostscript?

Tags: ghostscript

Ghostscript changes colospace to RGB when converting CMYK eps to jpeg.The problem is to keep colorspace untouched during conversion. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to *convert* any RGB that may be in the EPS to CMYK, use this command on Windows:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
   -o c:/path/to/output-cmyk.jpeg ^
   -sDEVICE=jpegcmyk ^
    input-rgb.eps
```

and this on Linux/Unix/MacOSX:

```
gs \
   -o /path/to/output-cmyk.jpeg \
   -sDEVICE=jpegcmyk \
    input-rgb.eps
```

Note, by default Ghostscript uses a resolution of 72 dpi for the JPEG output. If you want to change that to, say, 300 dpi, then add `-r300` to the commandline.

Comment: Ah jpgecmyk... this was driving me nuts.  Why does it just convert the color space by default.  You think it would attempt to use the same thing.

Anyhow this saved me a big headache.  Thanks!

Comment: Not working for me the combination of `-sDEVICE=jpegcmyk` and `r600` ! It outputs the jpg in good size but when I open it in Photoshop, it says 72dpi !! Any idea ?